# How to solve $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x -\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\arctan x -\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}$$

Is this $\dfrac00$ form?

Can I use L'Hôpital's rule like this:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\arctan x -\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x^2 +1} -\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x +1}}}{1}=\dfrac12$$

Or this limit does not exist!??

Only has $\mathop{\lim}\limits_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{\arctan x -\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}$ and $\mathop{\lim}\limits_{x \to 0^-}\dfrac{\arctan x -\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}$!??

Comment: Put $x=0$ to check yourself. But I believe the numerator should be $$\arctan x-\sqrt{x+1}+1$$

Comment: My bad, If that is +1 and can I use l'Hopital as above?

Comment: Your answer is fine. L'Hospital's Rule works. But an easier approach is to split the numerator by separating trigonometric part from algebraic part.

Comment: If you're going to apply L'Hospital's I reccomend just using the definition of the right sides derivative of $\arctan x + \sqrt{x+1}$ at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For the correct expression, we can avoid l'Hospital by

$$\dfrac{\arctan x +\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}=\dfrac{\arctan x }{x}+\dfrac{\sqrt{x +1} -1}{x}$$

and refer to standard limit for the first one (i.e. by $y=\tan x \to 0$) and the rationalization trick for the second one.

Comment: Why have you changed the surd's sign?

Comment: @J.G. I’m referring to what observed in the comments.

Comment: The comment discussed changing $-\sqrt{x+1}-1$ to $-\sqrt{x+1}+1$, not $\sqrt{x+1}-1$, although they both succumb to the same technique.

Comment: Ah ok! Yes indeed it is the same. Thanks

Comment: @user I have a question about last sentence: "and the rationalization trick for the second one". Isn't the second fraction rationalized already? because It has not root in the denominator. Did you mean multiply and divide the fraction by its conjugate?

Comment: Yes exactly! In this way we eliminate the indeterminacy.